# How do I add a UINavigationBar completely programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to figure out, given a `UIViewController` subclass, how to add a `UINavigationBar` to it. All the questions and answers seem to be either embed it in a navigation controller (not possible in this case) or via Storyboard, but I need to do it completely in code.

Do I just add it as a subview of the view controller's view? Will it become `topLayoutGuide` after I pin it to the `topLayoutGuide`, which would be the status bar prior to adding it? Or am I supposed to be setting an attribute on the view controller I cannot figure out, instead of adding it?

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track, you just add as a subview like you would any other view. The trick to the status bar is setting yourself as the navigationBar delegate and returning UIBarPositioningTopAttached in the delegate method

```
.....

self.customNavigationBar.delegate = self;
[self.addSubview self.navigationBar]; 

....

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositioningTopAttached;
}
```